# Что такое BoringSSL?

Tags: swift, alamofire

При компиляции никаких ошибок нет, но в консоле постоянно выскакивает несколько таких вот сообщений. От чего это может происходить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Что такое BoringSSL?" - BoringSSL это ответвление от OpenSSL.

"От чего это может происходить?" - У Вас уходит запрос на сервер с https, соответственно, сервер в ответ ругается. Смотрите, на что именно. Возможно, слишком много одновременных запросов.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/289618)

Comment: Развернул ответ.